# validity of a triangle

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics, education

Can a line segment be considered as a triangle, given that all three points(vertices) are collinear? if yes, then can a point be considered as a triangle too, considering all three vetrices lie at same position? Thanks.

Comment: I suppose it'd be problematic, because then it could also be a rectangle, irregular pentagon, and so-on - although various trigonometry still works, but something like triangulation of a ships position would not work if two beacons and a ship lined up (might not work)

Comment: What we usually call a triangle consists of 3 vertices which are distinct and non-collinear. i.e. they don't lie on any  single line. In those context where we want/need to treat those figures with 3 vertices lie on same line or vertices not distinct on equal footing like triangles, we will call those figures degenerate triangles. In reality, they are not triangles but some sort of "limit" of triangles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Definition of a triangle**

A triangle is a polygon with three edges and three vertices.In Euclidean geometry any three points, when non-collinear, determine a unique triangle and a unique plane (Wikipedia).

Triangle breaks up into 'tri' (three) and 'angle'.Three collinear points can never make three angles.So,your thinking is wrong.

Although what you are saying is technically considered to be a **degenerate triangle**.